# How to set checked for radio-fields a multiple time by classname if one has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use a small form having two radio buttons using multiple time in my page.

Radio buttons / "Form"

```
<input type="radio" name="myselection" class="my_classname" value="my_option1" checked>
<input type="radio" name="myselection" class="my_classname" value="my_option2">
```

This "Form" is used a second time in my page.

Now I want to make sure that all radio-buttons / all Forms has the same checked element after one is clicked/changed.

Is it possible and how Can I do it - I think with jquery/java-script?

```
  $(".my_classname").on('change', function() 
{   
 //do something!?
});
```

Thanks to teach and help me.

**UPDATE**

Maybe its imortant to know, that i use the input radio boxes in this way

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
     <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ">
             <input type="radio" name="my_name" class="my_classname1" value="my_value_1" autocomplete="off" checked> value 1
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active">
                      <input type="radio" name="my_name" class="my_classname1" value="my_value_2" autocomplete="off"> value 2
                    </label>
                  </div>
```

try like suggested answear in this ways failed

```
$('input:radio[class=my_classname1][value='+$(this).val()+']').prop('checked', true);
    $('input:radio[name=my_name][value='+$(this).val()+']').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: you can use $(".my_classname").prop("checked", true);

Comment: @JavascriptGeek i think it wont work, because it dosn not considered the current value after the change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this to set the same value to a another input in a form.

```js
 $(".my_classname").on('change', function() 
{   
  $('input:radio[name=myselection1]').val([$(this).val()]);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>original</b>

<input type="radio" name="myselection" class="my_classname" value="my_option1" checked>1st
<input type="radio" name="myselection" class="my_classname" value="my_option2">2nd
<br/>
<b>copy</b>
<input type="radio" name="myselection1" class="my_classname1" value="my_option1" checked>1st
<input type="radio" name="myselection1" class="my_classname1" value="my_option2">2nd
```

**Updated answer**

```js
$(".my_classname").on('change', function() 
{     
  $('input:radio[class=my_classname1][value='+$(this).val()+']').prop('checked', true);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>original</b>

<input type="radio" name="myselection" class="my_classname" value="my_option1" checked>1st
<input type="radio" name="myselection" class="my_classname" value="my_option2">2nd
<br/>
<b>copy</b>
<input type="radio" name="myselection1" class="my_classname1" value="my_option1" checked>1st
<input type="radio" name="myselection1" class="my_classname1" value="my_option2">2nd
```

Comment: Hi, thanks - i think i have to set "prop('checked', true);" is it possible to do it by using the classname and look for the selected value too?

Comment: @Marc_78 I updated my answer with class name and selected value

Comment: thanks, but it also wont work, i have update my post with the complete html code of the radio boxes, i actually use bootstraps, maybe thats the reason why it wont work?

Answer (score 0):

Listen the radio for changes and check all the radios that have the new selected value.

```js
$('.my_classname1').on('change', function () {
  $('[value="' + this.value + '"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Form 1</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="myselection" class="my_classname1" value="my_option1" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="myselection" class="my_classname1" value="my_option2">
  </fieldset>
</form>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Form 2</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="myselection" class="my_classname1" value="my_option1" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="myselection" class="my_classname1" value="my_option2">
  </fieldset>
</form>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Form 3</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="myselection" class="my_classname1" value="my_option1" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="myselection" class="my_classname1" value="my_option2">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: it looks good, but for me it doesn't work. Is it possible to combine the selector with the value (like in your suggestion) and additional the classname?

Comment: @Marc_78 I updated my answer using the correct class. Keep in mind that my solution works in both ways. If you change the radio of the 3rd form, it will change the values of form 1 and form 2. With the other answer, if you change the radio of the 2nd form, the first one will not be affected. Don't know which one you need.